# Facebook PHP API throwing array reference exception

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am re-asking this question. The original occurrence went away after retrying the post, but on Dec 9, it has happened again, with greater frequency. I now have over 140 requests backed up that are failing with this same error inside the Facebook PHP API, and retrying the posts still fails. Dumping out the value of $rawResponse header shows:

```
 {"
```

Just a left brace followed by a double quote, so it looks like the original function response is probably some JSON. Not sure what function made the original call, looking into that if I can make this happen in my DEV environment.

So, I just got back from vacation, and find that the Facebook PHP API was throwing this error:

> Undefined offset: 1 in /home/httpd/idxv3/lib/Facebook-v5/Http/GraphRawResponse.php on line 108

The line is in this function:

```
public function 
setHttpResponseCodeFromHeader($rawResponseHeader)
{
    preg_match('|HTTP/\d\.\d\s+(\d+)\s+.*|', $rawResponseHeader, $match);
    $this->httpResponseCode = (int)$match[1]; // <---- HERE
}
```

Other than the dangerous programming, why is this suddenly happening?

Comment: Because there is no match with `HTTP/\d\.\d\s+(\d+)` on the `(\d+)` so `$match[1]` doesn't exist.  What is `$rawResponseHeader` when that error occurs?

Comment: I understand what happens inside this function (which is why I call it dangerous - they are assuming that they will always get a match back from preg_match). This is on my production server, and it just showed up suddenly. I don't directly call this function - it is called several layers deep inside the Facebook API code. This is a php error, I can't trap for an exception.  Oddly, I have resubmitted the offending posts (for the 3rd time), and now the error doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: I hope, this solution will fix your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/58938305/10329023

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I generally tend to avoid changing code inside the Facebook library - what happens when there is an update? But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I believe that I have determined the problem. I recreated my Facebook API post inside the debugger, and determined that there is a block on the particular page I am posting to - but Facebook is returning a block of JSON code, which the API can't seem to handle. So, my question is moot - the API isn't written to handle the return values it might be getting from Facebook. Lovely.